# Checking values from other file in PHP

Tags: php

i am trying to figure out how to compare 2 diferent values from 2 different files. I'd like to compare the resources from one side to the oher side. And if i have more resourses than i need, then i want to appear the submit button.
Thank you all!
On both codes, i am converting from string to Int to make an easier comparison.
My problem is at the end of A code where im making an "IF" statement and i only want it as valid if all the conditions are done.

Code from file A, where are my cost of an upgrade. And a database returns all the buildings and the following costs to upgrade:

```
<table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><b><center>Actual</center></b></td>
    <td colspan="7"><b><center>Recursos per passar al proper nivell</center></b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><center>Edifici</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Nivell Actual</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Seguent Nivell</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Cristall</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Fusta</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Marbre</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Raim</center></b></td>
    <td><b><center>Sofre</center></b></td>
  </tr>
<?php
include("connexio.php");
  $consulta_edificis="SELECT nom_edifici,nivell FROM edificis ORDER BY id_edifici ASC"; //consultem el nom i el nivell acual del edifici
  $resultat_edificis=mysqli_query($connect,$consulta_edificis);
  while($consulta_nivell=mysqli_fetch_array($resultat_edificis)) //Treiem el nom i nivell actual.
  {
    $nivell_actual=(int)$consulta_nivell['nivell']; //convertim el string a numero enter
    $nivell_actual=$nivell_actual+1; //sumem 1 ja que a la taula de nivells també tenim el nivell 0.
    $consulta_seguent_nivell="SELECT id_nivell,cost_upgrade_cristall,cost_upgrade_fusta,cost_upgrade_marbre,cost_upgrade_raim,cost_upgrade_sofre FROM nivells LIMIT 1 OFFSET $nivell_actual"; //consulta per saber el que ens costarà pujar al seguent nivell.
    $resultat_pujar_nivell=mysqli_query($connect,$consulta_seguent_nivell);
    while($consulta_cost_seguent_nivell=mysqli_fetch_array($resultat_pujar_nivell))
    { //imprimim resultats
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_nivell['nom_edifici']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_nivell['nivell']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['id_nivell']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_cristall']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_fusta']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_marbre']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_raim']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_sofre']?></td>
        <?php
          $cost_cristall=(int)$consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_cristall'];
          $cost_fusta=(int)$consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_fusta'];
          $cost_marbre=(int)$consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_marbre'];
          $cost_raim=(int)$consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_raim'];
          $cost_sofre=(int)$consulta_cost_seguent_nivell['cost_upgrade_sofre'];
        ?>
        <?php include("materials.php"); ?>
        <td><?php if ($cristall>$cost_cristall && $fusta>$cost_fusta && $marbre>$cost_marbre && $raim>$cost_raim && $sofre>$cost_sofre): ?>
            <input type="submit" value="enviar">
            <?php else: ?>
            <p>no</p>
            <?php endif; ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php
    }
  }
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
</table>
```

Code from file B, where there are my resources:

```
    <?php
include("connexio.php");
$consulta_valors="SELECT * FROM materials LIMIT 1";
$resultat_valors=mysqli_query($connect,$consulta_valors);
while($consulta=mysqli_fetch_array($resultat_valors))
{
$consulta['cristall'];
$consulta['fusta'];
$consulta['marbre'];
$consulta['raim'];
$consulta['sofre'];
$cristall=(int)$consulta['cristall'];
$fusta=(int)$consulta['fusta'];
$marbre=(int)$consulta['marbre'];
$raim=(int)$consulta['raim'];
$sofre=(int)$consulta['sofre'];
}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
</table>
```